# FastAPI: Oauth2 implicit flow not passing the access token in subsequent apis

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, azure-ad-b2c, fastapiusers

I am implementing the Fastapi oauth2 implicit flow, while implementing I am able to receive the access token from azure ad, however the access token is not passed in subsequent apis.

In my swagger url the authorize button looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsGfs.png)

After successful login in UI I can see see this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cp5L.png)

I can also see the access token stored in the **browser local storage**, however in my subsequent api request the accessToken is not passed in curl url

curl url is formed like this

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8000/protected' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

Now in swagger redirect logic I have html like this

```
html = """
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Swagger UI: OAuth2 Redirect</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        'use strict';
        function run() {
            var oauth2 = window.opener.swaggerUIRedirectOauth2;
            var sentState = oauth2.state;
            var redirectUrl = oauth2.redirectUrl;
            var isValid, qp, arr;

            // Extract the query parameters from the URL fragment
            var fragment = window.location.hash.substring(1);
            var params = new URLSearchParams(fragment);

            // Extract the token from the fragment
            var accessToken = params.get('access_token');

            isValid = params.get('state') === sentState;

            // Store the access token securely in localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);

            // Callback with the token
            oauth2.callback({ auth: oauth2.auth, token: accessToken, isValid: isValid, redirectUrl: redirectUrl });

            window.close()
        }

        if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
            run();
        } else {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                run();
            });
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
        """
```

what should  I do that in curl request I can pass the access token?

Implemented the oauth2 implicit flow in fastapi, receiving the access token however the access token is not passed in subsequent apis curl request.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expect should happen: do you expect `curl` to parse the HTML, run the JavaScript, store the items in localStorage inside curl and then have it included in subsequence requests? Or are you asking how you can do this in JavaScript instead of using `curl`? Or are you asking how you can include the `Authorization` header in curl?

Comment: I have obtained access token from azure ad and also stored in browser local storage, My problem is when I make api call to my own apis than at that time curl request do not include the access token.

Do I need to do some process or Fastapi swagger should pick the access token stored in local storage?

Answer (score 1):

After looking for lot of solution I found that fastapi internally doesn't support implicit flow but it supports authorization code with pkce flow which is more secure than implicit flow.

There is a package which has good documentation to implement the authorization code with pkce flow.

Package name : [fastapi-azure-auth](https://github.com/Intility/fastapi-azure-auth)